# what is wrong in my code for twitter messages classification using NLTK in python

Tags: python

I am using nltk and naive bayes classifier to classify my tweets collection into three classes but when i measure the accouracy the recall get non value.
i m asking if anyone have an idea where the masteke.

```
    co_tweets = []
    pro_tweets = []
    in_tweets = []

    raw_tweets = csv.reader(open('d:/TRAN1.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=',')
    tweets = []
    for row in raw_tweets:

        if len(row) <= 1:
                pass
        else:
                category = row[0]
                tweet = row[1]

                item = (tweet, category)
                tweets.append(item)
                if category == "co":
                   co_tweets += item
                elif category =="in":
                    in_tweets += item
                else:
                    pro_tweets += item

    cocutoff, procutoff,incutoff = len(co_tweets) * 3 / 4, len(pro_tweets) * 3 / 4, len(in_tweets)
    co_train, co_test = co_tweets[:cocutoff], co_tweets[cocutoff:]
    pro_train, pro_test = pro_tweets[:procutoff], pro_tweets[procutoff:]
    in_train, in_test = in_tweets[:incutoff], in_tweets[incutoff:]

    co_feats_train = get_train_features_from_tweets(co_train, 'co')
    pro_feats_train = get_train_features_from_tweets(pro_train, 'pro')
    in_feats_train = get_train_features_from_tweets(in_train, 'in')

    train_feats = co_feats_train + pro_feats_train + in_feats_train
    co_feats_test = get_train_features_from_tweets(co_test, 'co')
    in_feats_test = get_train_features_from_tweets(in_test, 'in')
    pro_feats_test = get_train_features_from_tweets(pro_test, 'pro')
    test_feats1 = co_feats_test + in_feats_test + pro_feats_test 


    #classifier = SvmClassifier.train(train_feats)
    classifier1 = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_feats)
    correct, wrong = 0, 0
    for tweet in co_test:
        features = get_features_from_tweet(tweet)
        result = classifier1.classify(features)
        if result == "co":
            correct +=1
        else:
            wrong += 1


    for tweet in pro_test:
        features = get_features_from_tweet(tweet)
        result = classifier1.classify(features)
        if result == "pro":
            correct += 1
        else:
            wrong += 1
    for tweet in in_test:
        features = get_features_from_tweet(tweet)
        result = classifier1.classify(features)
        if result == "in":
            correct += 1
        else:
            wrong += 1       

    referenceSets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    testSets = collections.defaultdict(set)
    shuffle(train_feats)
    K_FOLDS = 10
    print("Shuffling Done")
    X_folds = np.array_split(train_feats, K_FOLDS)


    scores = list()
    for k in range(K_FOLDS):
        X_train = list(X_folds)
        X_test = X_train.pop(k)
        X_train = np.concatenate(X_train)
        classifier_sub = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(X_train)
        scores.append(nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier_sub, X_test))

    print("K-Fold scores done ", scores)

    for i, (features, label) in enumerate(test_feats1):
            referenceSets[label].add(i)
            predicted = classifier1.classify(features)
            testSets[predicted].add(i)        
    print 'sentiment classifier accuracy:'       

    print "Accuracy: {}".format(correct / float(correct + wrong))
    print 'Average accuracy K-Fold ', sum(scores) / float(len(scores))
    print 'co precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(referenceSets['co'], testSets['co'])
    print 'co recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(referenceSets['co'], testSets['co'])
    print 'co f-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(referenceSets['co'], testSets['co'])
    print 'in precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(referenceSets['in'], testSets['in'])
    print 'in recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(referenceSets['in'], testSets['in'])
    print 'in f-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(referenceSets['in'], testSets['in'])
    print 'pro precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(referenceSets['pro'], testSets['pro'])
    print 'pro recall:', nltk.metrics.recall(referenceSets['pro'], testSets['pro'])
    print 'pro f-measure:', nltk.metrics.f_measure(referenceSets['pro'], testSets['pro'])

Shuffling Done
('K-Fold scores done ', [0.8731343283582089, 0.8880597014925373, 0.8796992481203008, 0.8421052631578947, 0.849624060150376, 0.8571428571428571, 0.8872180451127819, 0.8571428571428571, 0.8345864661654135, 0.8872180451127819])
sentiment classifier accuracy:
Accuracy: 0.848739495798
Average accuracy K-Fold  0.865593087196
co precision: 1.0
co recall: 0.772357723577
co f-measure: 0.871559633028
in precision: 0.0
in recall: None
in f-measure: None
pro precision: 0.91452991453
pro recall: 0.930434782609
pro f-measure: 0.922413793103
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the doc

> Given a set of reference values and a set of test values, return the fraction of reference values that appear in the test set. In particular, return card(reference intersection test)/card(reference). If reference is empty, then return None.

I would say that

```
referenceSets['in']
```

is empty, so the fact that None is returned is expected.

Could you check the content to confirm this.

Comment: how can i check its content